# EU spam legislation Spain, which action can be taken and to whom?

Tags: privacy, european-union, spain

Me and hundreds of other people are receiving a unsolicited emails from a major Spanish based airline. They seem to not have an unsubscription feature and when contacted they refuse to delete emails addresses.

I would like to know what action can be raised against them and eventually who to contact.

Comment: There was legislation before you were able to call, and good news now there's the EU legislation too.